# ¿Como saber si una variable ha sido inicializada(Kotlin)?

Tags: android, kotlin

Estoy usando Kotlin y al inicio de mí aplicación declaro una variable que inicializo más tarde, con el objetivo de no declararla como nula en un comienzo y así evitar los molestos signos de Nullabilidad(!!):

```
private lateinit var variableName: Type
```

En cierto punto deseo saber si la variable ya ha sido inicializada que realice determinada instrucción, en caso contrario que lo ignore.

Ya intente usar LET, pero no me funciona.

```
variableName.let{ código }
```

pretendo saber si se puede hacer algo similar a

```
if(variableName.isInitialized){}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En la versión 1.2 de kotlin que actualmente se encuentra en su versión beta2 se ha incluido una funcionalidad para conocer cuando una variable lateinit ya ha sido inicializada.

```
lateinit var file: File
// ...
if (::file.isInitialized) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No se puede utilizar `lateinit` antes de inicializar la variable por lo que verificar si esta inicializada con `lateinit` lanzara `UninitializedPropertyAccessException`. En tu caso tampoco puedes utilizar [`lazy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-lazy/index.html) ya que solo se puede asignar el valor en la definicion de la variable y el valor no puede cambiar.

La unica opcion que veo es cambiandola a `nullable` y verificar si esta `null`:

```
private var variableName: Type?

    //..

    if(variableName.isNull())
    {

    }
```

Comment: Gracias, no quería hacer eso, pero no quedará de otra.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es al momento de incializar la variable darle el valor de null:

```
 var variableName: Type? = null
```

De este modo la siguiente linea de código funcionara perfectamente:

```
if(variableName != null){...}
```

y se consigue el mismo efecto que si utilizaras una variable ni inicio tardío

Answer (score 0):

```
val variablename: String = "Carlos"
    if (variablename != null) {
        // Si no es nula escribimos el nombre de la variable en mayuscula
        println(variablename .toUpperCase())
    }
```

Comment: Esto no aplica en este caso, solo si la variable fue definida con "inicialización tardía" usando lateinit.

Answer (score 0):

**El verificar si una variable fue inicializada previamente, solo aplica cuando usas "inicialización tardía" mediante la palabra clave `lateinit`.**

`lateinit` evita que la variable se inicialice en el momento de la construcción del objeto de su clase.

Para verificar si una variable fue inicializada o no, usamos [**isInitialized**](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/is-initialized.html).

Ejemplo:

En este ejemplo indicará que `variableName` no fue inicializada.

```
private lateinit var variableName: String

     fun main() {

       val numbers = listOf("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six")
       println(numbers.first { it.length > 3 })
       println(numbers.last { it.startsWith("f") })       
       for (i in numbers.indices) {
          println(i)
       }
      
       //*Verifica si variableName fue previamente inicializada. 
       if (::variableName.isInitialized) {
          println("Fue inicializada!")
       }else{
          println("No fue inicializada!")
       }
      
  }
```

En este ejemplo indicará que `variableName` fue previamente inicializada:

```
private lateinit var variableName: String

     fun main() {

       //*inicializa variable.  
       variableName = "Hola StackOverflow!"  
         
       val numbers = listOf("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six")
       println(numbers.first { it.length > 3 })
       println(numbers.last { it.startsWith("f") })       
       for (i in numbers.indices) {
          println(i)
       }
      
       //*Verifica si variableName fue previamente inicializada. 
       if (::variableName.isInitialized) {
          println("Fue inicializada!")
       }else{
          println("No fue inicializada!")
       }
      
  }
```